# icon Split Action Bar android code

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I try to do Action menu like that

```
http://www.auipatterns.com/2013/02/split-action-bar.html
```

I want any simple source code that help me to undrstand and do it .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Split Action Bar](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/06/split-action-bar-for-android-4.html)

The link above might help with your question